# 404 error using Python with Computer Vision API analyzing web-based images

Tags: python, computer-vision

I have no problems using an Azure Computer Vision API service in C# using the same region/key but Python is giving me fits. I can't analyze anything from the web. Here is the snippet from a sample:

```
_region = 'westus' #Here you enter the region of your subscription
_url = 'https://{}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0'.format(_region)
_key = "<my API Key>"
_maxNumRetries = 10

# URL direction to image
urlImage = "https://oxfordportal.blob.core.windows.net/vision/Analysis/1-1.jpg"

# Computer Vision parameters
params = { 'visualFeatures' : 'Color,Categories'} 

headers = dict()
headers['Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'] = _key
headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json' 

json = { 'url': urlImage } 
data = None

result = processRequest( json, data, headers, params )
```

I have tried numerous images with variations of the above, but I never get anything but a 404 - Resource not found error. Where am I going wrong? Is it a problem with the service or the URL? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File this under "never mind". The problem was due to a missing slash after the url. I was copying the link from Azure, but it doesn't add it automatically and I missed it in the code.